# Conceptual question about the definition of "The Image of $S$ under the map $f$"

Tags: functions, predicate-logic

In Tao's *Analysis I*, the definition of an **image** of some subset $S$ is given as follows:

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, and $S$ is a set in $X$, we defined $f(S)$ to be the set:
>
> $f(S):=\{f(x):x\in S\}$

Now, when I first read this, I thought I had a very clear picture of what this conveyed. However, after running through some of the exercises at the end of the chapter, I realized that I misunderstood what was entailed by this definition.

My initial interpretation of this definition (*in plain english*) was: "If $x \notin S$, $y \notin f(S)$." The reasoning for this was that I thought $\{f(x):x\in S\}$ effectively meant $y: [(y =f (x) )\land (x \in S)]$ where "$(y =f (x) )\land (x \in S)$" is some proposition of the form $P(x,y)$. Therefore, if $x \notin S$, this statement is false, and thus $y \notin f(S)$.

After running through the exercises, **I realized that my interpretation was wrong**. Let's consider the statement $x^* \notin S$.

When we say $y \in f(S)$, what we are really saying is that IF $y \in f(S)$ then there must exist an $ x \in S$ that generates this $y$. However, it could certainly be the case that there are OTHER elements, such as $x^*$, which are NOT in $S$, that **also map** to $f(S)$. As such, just because an element like $x^*$ is NOT in $S$, it is not necessarily true that $f(x^*) \notin f(S)$.

So it seems like my initial interpretation should *actually* have been "If $(\neg\exists x \in S $ s.t.$ y=f(x)) \land f(x^*) =y$, then $y \notin f(S)$".

My question is as follows:

Why was my reasoning wrong, which led to the initial misinterpretation? Is there a more symbolically heavy way of describing the set $f(S)$ to avoid the confusion that I encountered?

Comment: To whoever downvoted this question: can you please explain to the OP why you consider this question so bad it warrants a downvote? It's well formatted, thought out, and overall a *good* question, if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial misinterpretation was due to the fact that you did not include quantifiers in it. That is, you wrote that $f(S)$ should be

$$\{y| y=f(x)\land x\in S\}$$ however the $x$ in this definition is unquantified. The correct version of this would be
$$\{y| \exists x: (y=f(x)\land x\in S)\}$$

while you understood it more as

$$\{y| \forall x: (y=f(x)\implies x\in S)\}$$ which is incorrect.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @S.Cramer Happy to help.

Comment: out of curiosity, $\{y:\forall x: (y=f(x) \implies x \in S) \}$ seems to be logically equivalent to $\{y:\exists ! x : (y=f(x) \land x \in S)\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @S.Cramer No. The statements are not logically equivalent.

Comment: Oh, that is surprising. They seem to describe the same set. If possible, could you please provide me with a scenario where the second set contains an element that the first set would not? (or vice versa)

Comment: @S.Cramer Take the function $f(x)=x^2$, mapping from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Then the first set contains $-1$, while the second does not. The first contains $-1$, because $y=f(x)$ is always false, and if $A$ is false, then $A\implies B$ is always true.

Comment: ohhh, so the first set can be populated by vacuously true statements as well. Gotch you gotch you. Thanks so much!